Isolating Docker on a Separate Drive in Linux
I have Linux Ubuntu installed along with Docker. I would like to move all Docker-related files to a separate, mounted drive. Is this even possible? I managed to move the contents from /var/lib/docker, but there are still files like docker.sock. Is there a way to completely isolate Docker on a different drive?

docker.sock is usually located on a ram drive, not on a disk. Is there a particular reason why you need to change it's location? (which is documented).

I thought that if something happened to Ubuntu, I wouldn’t have to worry about something happening to Docker (since it would be on a different drive). If I move the contents of the /var/lib/docker folder, is there any reason to be concerned about this?

For example, I mean a scenario where I would need to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.

The socket file is created when the daemon starts and deleted when it stops. It's just a communication socket. It doesn't hold any data at all.

What problem are you solving? Isolating disk usage, slow drive, configuring root as read-only, attempting to move an install by physically moving a drive, something else?

I have in mind a scenario where, for some reason (e.g., system damage), I would need to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. In such a case, I would like to be able to restore Docker without any issues (by storing data on a separately mounted disk). Is simply transferring the contents of /var/lib/docker sufficient for this?
